# Converting Raman Spectra to Infrared Spectra

Tags: spectroscopy, raman

I have data for detecting a substance using Raman spectra, but in production, I plan to be using a visible & near-infrared spectrometer. Would it be possible for me to convert from the Raman values to visible & near-infrared values? Are they the same? Thank you.

Comment: They are in general not the same. In particular, for molecules with a center of symmetry, the vibrational modes that are detected by Raman are exactly the modes not detected by IR spectroscopy and vice versa.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not in any way that you can use in practice for getting a working predictive model (= data analysis procedure).

---

Depending on the molecular symmetry of your analyte(s), infrared and Raman spectra may share some bands, or not: a vibration can be infrared-active, Raman-active, or both. 
Near-infrared spectra show combinations and overtones of the infrared-active bands, and that makes them far more complex and complicated to analyze.

Now, if you know your analyte(s) and the matrix and both are sufficiently simple, one may arrive at educated guesses Raman vs. infrared spectrum.

But this is in general not sufficient to develop a full predictive method for production use: typically, a successful method needs to take into account the type and size of variations that occur (in the production process) and which ones are expected and OK and which ones are not. Particularly in a production environment, relevant variations may be due to physical effects (e.g. particle size, ambient temperature, ...) rather than concentration variations of the consitituents of your mixture.

In general, you cannot expect to get anything close to a working NIR spectroscopic method without running a well-designed calibration experiment and the appropriate statistical analysis.

Also keep in mind: 
In theory, there is no difference between theory and practice. In practice, there is.

---

Whatever your production is, please go and consult someone who knows about vibrational spectroscopy and if you plan to use near infrared spectra, also about chemometrics (statistical data analysis). If you have a third wish free: ask for someone who in addition knows about your field/domain/application.